# Loading JavaScript file and access it from ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables, load

I'm trying to load a JavaScript file from a URL in my React application.

I'm using a <script> in the head of HTML of my project. I can see it loaded in the network of the console Chrome, and that's OK.

Now I'm trying to use a function from this file in my React application, with window.nameOfTheFunction, but I cannot access it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using the window function is non ideal. How you do it depends on where the .js code is.

#### JavaScript on your server

If the JavaScript is located on your server then the best way to approach it is to bundle the JavaScript code with a bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and then use the import function.

#### JavaScript on a remote server

If you want to use JavaScript from a remote server then you need to load the code and confirm it's loaded before using it. The reason is that some code may load slower from your source due to its size or network traffic and you don't want your code to break because of those reasons. The following code should help:

```
function App() {
  const status = useScript(
    'https://pm28k14qlj.codesandbox.io/test-external-script.js'
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Script status: <b>{status}</b>
      </div>
      {status === "ready" && (
        <div>
          Script function call response: <b>{TEST_SCRIPT.start()}</b>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

// Hook
function useScript(src) {
  // Keep track of script status ("idle", "loading", "ready", "error")
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(src ? "loading" : "idle");

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      // Allow falsy src value if waiting on other data needed for
      // constructing the script URL passed to this hook.
      if (!src) {
        setStatus("idle");
        return;
      }

      // Fetch existing script element by src
      // It may have been added by another intance of this hook
      let script = document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`);

      if (!script) {
        // Create script
        script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.async = true;
        script.setAttribute("data-status", "loading");
        // Add script to document body
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        // Store status in attribute on script
        // This can be read by other instances of this hook
        const setAttributeFromEvent = (event) => {
          script.setAttribute(
            "data-status",
            event.type === "load" ? "ready" : "error"
          );
        };

        script.addEventListener("load", setAttributeFromEvent);
        script.addEventListener("error", setAttributeFromEvent);
      } else {
        // Grab existing script status from attribute and set to state.
        setStatus(script.getAttribute("data-status"));
      }

      // Script event handler to update status in state
      // Note: Even if the script already exists we still need to add
      // event handlers to update the state for *this* hook instance.
      const setStateFromEvent = (event) => {
        setStatus(event.type === "load" ? "ready" : "error");
      };

      // Add event listeners
      script.addEventListener("load", setStateFromEvent);
      script.addEventListener("error", setStateFromEvent);

      // Remove event listeners on cleanup
      return () => {
        if (script) {
          script.removeEventListener("load", setStateFromEvent);
          script.removeEventListener("error", setStateFromEvent);
        }
      };
    },
    [src] // Only re-run effect if script src changes
  );

  return status;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i can load my file perfectly with that, but i want to use the function directly in the code not in a return like a window.TEST_SCRIPT   do you know , how i can do ?

Comment: The code above will allow you to use the function directly. Given your question, I'm assuming that the .js code was written by someone else and you want to know how to include it in your application. How you include and use it depends on whether it's a module or not. You can read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules If you want to include a module, then the next issue is how you're writing your code. Not every setup / IDE supports loading modules. What IDE are you using?

Comment: the file i want to use is generate by playcanvas my client put it on a server and i try to use it in my react app, i'm using webstorm and vscode

Comment: This guy -  https://forum.playcanvas.com/u/IRONMANROMEO has successfully integrated playcanvas with react on his website - it might be worth contacting him :)

Comment: thans jaesle, i integrate too in my react app , now i try to make that dynamic , i try to bring all playcanvas files from url,  and that module make me crazy lol , anyway will find an issue and post it here, by the way sorry for my english maybe my problem is not really clear